# Calculating voltage at the output of a circuit

Tags: resistors, diodes

I have \$U_E\$ as sawtooth signal as shown in the figure, I don't know how to calculate the voltage at the output \$U_A\$.

I have made $$I = U_A - U_E/R_1$$ and $$U_E = U_q + IR_1 - U_D + IR_2$$

but still I'm missing the calculation of the unknown \$I\$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry I can't make heads or tails of your schematic, I could guess.. but.

Comment: what can't you see in the schematic ?

Comment: I see lots of arrows, what is the circle with a 10 V arrow, is that your source?  Are the ends shorted?  It's just not clear.   (Sorry.. there is a schematic editor.)

Comment: @George Herold The circle with 10V is a voltage source , the ends are not shorted, that arrow is a direction.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold I made a sketch of the circuit, UE is a sawtooth as shown in the figure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Let's just consider the first period of the sawtooth waveform, the output pattern will be similar for the later states.

$$U_e = 6t - 30, \quad 0 < t < 10\;ms $$

Current \$I\$ flows only when diode is forward biased i.e \$U_{QR} > U_d\$

Considering \$U_p\$ as ground reference potential, while the diode is off 
\$U_p = U_r = 0\$

For the current to flow, diode must turn on.

The diode turns on when \$U_s > -10 + U_d\$  (The potential at node \$Q\$ should be \$U_d\$, the voltage source behind it increases the potential of node \$T\$ (or \$S\$) by 10 V , so \$U_s\$ can be 10 V lower than \$U_d\$ for diode to turn on).

Now there are two cases to be considered:

#### Case I

\$-30 < U_e < -10 + U_d \$

- Diode is off
- \$I\$ does not flow

So, \$U_e = U_a\$, meaning output tracks the input waveform.

#### Case II

\$-10 + U_d < U_e < 30\$

- Diode is on, hence \$I\$ flows.

In loop PSTR, applying KVL:

$$ U_e - 1.8i + 10 - U_d - 3.2i = 0 $$

$$ U_e - U_d + 10 = 5i $$

$$ i = \frac{U_e - U_d + 10}{5} $$

where \$U_e = 6t - 30\$ (you need to find exact time instant where diode turns on, I cannot do this as \$U_d\$ is not given).

In this case,

$$ U_a = U_e - 1.8i + 10 - U_d $$

In this equation you can replace \$i\$ with equation given above, and you will have all the known values except for \$U_d\$ (which is typically \$0.7V\$ for diodes), from here on it is easy to plot.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

OK that's nicer. (I'm going to call all your U's, V's) 
 Let's see, first what is the output if all that stuff in the middle is gone.  Just Ve and R1.. what's Va?

Second question,
How much current is flowing through the middle bit, (diode and R2) if the voltage at the output node (Va) is greater than 10 V?

Now what happens when the output voltage falls below 10 V?
(or ~10.6 V... It depends on what your diode model.)
What is your diode model.

OK .. maybe you can carry on from here.  (What happens when diode turns on.. is forward biased?)